# HTTP.get request don't return elements when getting value from localstorage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm currently finishing a project but I have a little issue.

I'm storing a value in local (it's working).
I want to retrieve this value in my Provider, I can retrieve it, but I can't use it in this.http.get function.

I'd like to be able to call this.http.get with the value which is stored.

My cours-services.ts which is **not working** :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {resolveId} from "@ionic/app-scripts/dist/rollup/ionic-rollup-resolver-plugin";

/*
 Generated class for the CoursService provider.

 See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
 for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
 */
@Injectable()
export class CoursService {
  data: any;
  identifiant: string;

  constructor(public http: Http, private storage: Storage) {
    console.log('Hello CoursService Provider');
    this.storage = storage;
  }

  getName() {

  };

  load() {
    if (this.data) {
      // already loaded data
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    // don't have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // We're using Angular HTTP provider to request the data,
      // then on the response, it'll map the JSON data to a parsed JS object.
      // Next, we process the data and resolve the promise with the new data.

      this.storage.get('identifiant').then((identifiant) => {
        this.identifiant = identifiant
      })

      this.http.get('https://api.corentincloss.fr/intranet/edt.php?id=' + this.identifiant)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
          // and save the data for later reference
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
  }

}
```

returning this object where data is **null** :

[image]

And now my cours-service.ts which is **working when I manually define this.identifiant** :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {resolveId} from "@ionic/app-scripts/dist/rollup/ionic-rollup-resolver-plugin";

/*
 Generated class for the CoursService provider.

 See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
 for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
 */
@Injectable()
export class CoursService {
  data: any;
  identifiant: string;

  constructor(public http: Http, private storage: Storage) {
    console.log('Hello CoursService Provider');
    this.storage = storage;
  }

  getName() {

  };

  load() {
    if (this.data) {
      // already loaded data
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    // don't have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // We're using Angular HTTP provider to request the data,
      // then on the response, it'll map the JSON data to a parsed JS object.
      // Next, we process the data and resolve the promise with the new data.

      /*this.storage.get('identifiant').then((identifiant) => {
        this.identifiant = identifiant
      })*/

      this.identifiant = 'closs006'

      this.http.get('https://api.corentincloss.fr/intranet/edt.php?id=' + this.identifiant)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
          // and save the data for later reference
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
  }

}
```

returning this object where data **contains things** :

[image]

I'm searching since like 2 maybe 3 hours and I don't find how to do...

Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you know that `this.storage.get` is a asynchronous way, you won't get what you want immediately. so you have to move the http.get into `this.storage.get().then()`.

```
this.storage.get('identifiant').then((identifiant) => {
    this.identifiant = identifiant

    this.http.get('https://api.corentincloss.fr/intranet/edt.php?id=' + this.identifiant)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
            // and save the data for later reference
            this.data = data;
            resolve(this.data);
        });
  })
```

Comment: I love you, thank you ! I wasn't trying with this.identifiant when I tried this solution, only "identifiant" and it wasn't working

Comment: @Unyxos Ahha, glad it helped. :-)